# Amazon S3 to Glacier with Lifecycle - No Glacier Available

Tags: amazon-glacier

I have an Amazon S3 bucket that I wish to transfer to Amazon Glacier.  I have created a Glacier vault with open permissions.  When I try to create a life cycle rule to transfer to Glacier, nothing comes up (see pic).  What am I missing?  I have consulted the documentation to no avail.

[image]

Comment: In what region is the S3 bucket?

Comment: Singapore, which doesn't support Glacier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon Glacier is not available in all AWS regions yet.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#glacier_region

Comment: Transferring the data from Singapore to Tokyo fixed the problem.